# Different ways to communication between nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

There seem to be quite a few ways of communicating between directives. Say you have nested directives, where the inner directives must communicate something to the outer (e.g. it's been chosen by the user).

```
<outer>
  <inner></inner>
  <inner></inner>
</outer>
```

So far I have 5 ways of doing this

### `require:` parent directive

The `inner` directive can require the `outer` directive, which can expose some method on its controller. So in the `inner` definition

```
require: '^outer',
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, outerController) {
   // This can be passed to ng-click in the template
   $scope.chosen = function() {
     outerController.chosen(something);
   }
}
```

And in the `outer` directive's controller:

```
controller: function($scope) {
   this.chosen = function(something) {
   }
}
```

### `$emit` event

The `inner` directive can `$emit` an event, which the `outer` directive can respond to, via `$on`. So in the `inner` directive's controller:

```
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.chosen = function() {
    $scope.$emit('inner::chosen', something);
  }
}
```

and in the `outer` directives controller:

```
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('inner::chosen, function(e, data) {
  }
}
```

### Execute expression in parent scope, via `&`

The item can bind to an expression in the parent scope, and execute it at an appropriate point. The HTML would be like:

```
<outer>
  <inner inner-choose="functionOnOuter(item)"></inner>
  <inner inner-choose="functionOnOuter(item)"></inner>
</outer>
```

So the `inner` controller has an 'innerChoose' function it can call

```
scope: {
  'innerChoose': '&'
},
controller: function() {
  $scope.click = function() {
    $scope.innerChoose({item:something});
  }
}
```

which would call (in this case) the 'functionOnOuter' function on the `outer` directive's scope:

```
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.functionOnOuter = function(item) {
  }
}
```

### Scope inheritance on non-isolated scope

Given that these are nested controllers, scope inheritance can be at work, and the inner directive can just call any functions in the scope chain, as long as it doesn't have an isolated scope). So in the `inner` directive:

```
// scope: anything but a hash {}
controller: function() {
  $scope.click = function() {
    $scope.functionOnOuter(something);
  }
}
```

And in the `outer` directive:

```
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.functionOnOuter = function(item) {
  }
}
```

### By service injected into both inner and outer

A service can be injected into both directives, so they can have direct access to the same object, or call functions to notify the service, and maybe even register themselves to be notified, in a pub/sub system. This doesn't require the directives to be nested.

**Question**: What are any potential drawbacks and advantages of each over the others?

**Credit/Disclaimer**: This is not my question, I found the [original question on programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223006/communication-between-nested-directives).The [original author](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/111969/michal-charemza) never moved it over here as suggested.

Comment: IMHO, I prefer require: parent directive and Execute expression in parent scope, via &. And the recommended way is to use "Execute expression in parent scope, via &.". use $emit only when you have no other options.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out to the original author.

Here are when I think each situation should be preffered:

### Use `require` parent directive if

- inner is always inside outer
- inner always call the same outer API
- inner is private, the developper interacts with outer

### Use $emit event if

- The two directives has nothing in common, especially hierarchy
- The need for communication rely on an event
- You feel too lazy to create a service for it

### Execute expression in parent scope, via `&` if

- inner doesn't need to be always inside outer
- inner doesn't always call the same API from outer, or with the same parameters

### Use scope inheritance on non-isolated scope if

Nah, don't. It is same as using `require` except you don't guarantee inner will be inside outer, and it become very unclear for a programmer how to use that directive.

### Use a service injected into both inner and outer if

- You are in the same situation as with the `$emit` case
- But you are a good person

---

That's about it. A service is always better than a broadcast because it explicitely tell the programmer which events have an effect on the directive. Using `$emit` and the like is really the wrost option most of the time, as it all behave like the old school `goto` expression that many developpers love to hate: you'll have a bad time trying to debug your directives when you have too many events.

Now if the hierarchy is guaranteed and the API fixed I recommend using `require` as it becomes one less worry for the developper using the directives.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point another way for directive to interact - via objects:

```
<outer model='model'>
  <inner model='model[0]'></inner>
  <inner model='model[1]'></inner>
</outer>
```

Or more familiar case:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="smth"/>
<div ng-show="smth"></div>
```